# Add markets to Google Maps APi v2 of places within a radius of the users location

Tags: android, google-maps, geolocation

Hi I am currently working on a project where i need to show a whole load of locations stored in a database on the google maps within a radius around the users current location.

I currently have the users location and a radius that is set by the user via a seekbar. How do I as effeciently as possible search through a database and get the lat and lons within the database table that are within the radius around the user and display them on google maps as markers.

Mainly im looking for an efficent way to query the database as i can get the markets on the map easily from that point.

Comment: You need to query the database and select points within a bounding circle radius. Take look at [here](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong-db.html), it will give a better query suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to read on the new MySQL 5.7 geospatial features. For example in [this post about using some of the MySQL 5.7 geospatial functionalities](http://mysqlserverteam.com/mysql-5-7-and-gis-an-example/) it's author discusses very similar problem to yours. MySQL 5.7 also supports spatial indexes, so it allows faster search in spatial data. Another option is to run MySQL together with Sphinx, which also provides [functionality for geospatial search](http://sphinxsearch.com/blog/2014/09/05/a-geospatial-search-odysse/).